# Esper expression not working

Tags: java, reserved-words, esper

I am currently learning [Esper expressions](http://esper.codehaus.org/tutorials/tutorial/tutorial.html) and I am quite confused. I have a simple example that simulates a Humidity sensor that streams numbers every few secnods. With my reading I did a quite complex example:

```
select avg(value), 'Humidity' as datasource, from myPackage.myClass(name='Humidity').win:time(50 sec)
```

However, Esper gives me an error. It says that I am using a reserved word near 'from'. Why do I get this error? What is wrong in this expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably just the comma between "datasource, from"